# Airflow instance does not connect to edge-node server through SFTPsensor (SSH connection type)

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, airflow, sftp, directed-acyclic-graphs

My goal is to make an Airflow DAG check if a file exists in a directory inside a different server (in this case, an edge-node from a cluster).

**My first approach** was to make a SSHOperator which triggered a bash script (in the edge-node server) that checks if the directory is empty. This worked. I was able to receive the output from the bash script in the DAG logs telling me if the dir is empty or not. However, when the SSHOperator fails (ie, the script did not found a file in the dir) the current dag run is interrupted and a new dag run starts. If this happens multiple times (which is expected) I will end up with a tonne of interrupted dag runs in the tree view =/

So, **my second approach** is to use a proper sensor. In this case, the SFTPSensor seems to be the best option.

So here is my python DAG code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models import Variable
import requests
import logging
import time
from airflow.contrib.sensors.sftp_sensor import SFTPSensor
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def say_bye(**context):
    print("byebyeeee!")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
}

ssh_id = Variable.get("ssh_connection_id_imb")
source_path = "/trf/cq/millennium/rcp/"

dag = DAG(dag_id='ing_cgd_millennium_t_ukajrnl_imb_test4', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

with dag:

    s0 = SFTPSensor(
        task_id='sensing_task',
        path=source_path,
        fs_conn_id=ssh_id,
        poke_interval=60,
        mode='reschedule',
        retries=1
        )

    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='run_this_goodbye',python_callable=say_bye,provide_context=True)

    s0 >> t1
```

My SSH connection (ssh_connection_id_imb) looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7iLu.png

And the error:

```
[2021-03-09 11:56:07,662] {base_hook.py:89} INFO - Using connection to: id: sftp_default. Host: localhost, Port: 22, Schema: None, Login: airflow, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2021-03-09 11:56:07,664] {base_hook.py:89} INFO - Using connection to: id: sftp_default. Host: localhost, Port: 22, Schema: None, Login: airflow, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2021-03-09 11:56:07,665] {sftp_sensor.py:46} INFO - Poking for lpc600.group.com:/trf/cq/millenium/rcp/C.PGMLNGL.FKM001.041212.20201123.gz
[2021-03-09 11:56:07,665] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - /opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from /root/.ssh/known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
[2021-03-09 11:56:07,666] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Unable to connect to localhost: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py", line 107, in execute
    while not self.poke(context):
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/sensors/sftp_sensor.py", line 48, in poke
    self.hook.get_mod_time(self.path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py", line 219, in get_mod_time
    conn = self.get_conn()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py", line 114, in get_conn
    self.conn = pysftp.Connection(**conn_params)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._start_transport(host, port)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 176, in _start_transport
    self._transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 416, in __init__
    "Unable to connect to {}: {}".format(hostname, reason)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to localhost: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I noticed that the base_hook is pointing to localhost and the sftp_sensor is pointing to the correct server.... do I need to set up the base hook?? Am I missing a step?? Thanks for the help! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized my errors...

Problem #1 **bad sftp_connection name**:

```py
s0 = SFTPSensor(
        task_id='sensing_task',
        path=source_path,
        sftp_conn_id=ssh_id, # instead of fs_conn_id
        poke_interval=60,
        mode='reschedule',
        retries=1
        )
```

Problem #2 **Extra** field needs to be defined in the connection

I created a public key and add this to the Extra field:

```json
{"key_file": "/airflow/generated_sshkey_dir/id_rsa.pub", "no_host_key_check": true}
```

Sooo, this makes my connection prone to a **man in the middle attack**, since I'm not checking for the host key. In my case, this solution is sufficient.